# iOSからpostを投げて、jbuilderでjsonを返したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Rails4 の jbuilderでpostを実装したいです。
iOSからpostを投げましたが、nillが帰ってきてしまいます。

api/v1/events/index.json.jbuilder

```
json.events @events
```

app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end
end
```

app/controllers/events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.json { render json: 'ok!', status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: 'Bad!', status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start_time, :end_time)
  end
end
```

もしかすると、createアクションをapiのコントローラーにも書く必要があるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> もしかすると、createアクションをapiのコントローラーにも書く必要があるのでしょうか。

はい。そうです。

iOSからのpost先が`Api::V1::EventsController`でしたら`Api::V1::EventsController`に`EventsController`相当の`create`メソッドの実装が必要です。

また、routesをこのように定義している時

config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :events, only: [:index, :create]
  end
end
```

このようなリクエストで登録処理ができると思います。

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"event": {"title": "TITLE"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events
```

また、`ApplicationController`の`protect_from_forgery`を`:null_session`にすることで登録できると思います。

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
その時のiOS側に渡すurlは/api/v1/events.jsonで合っているでしょうか。。

Comment: ケースバイケースなので回答にroutesとリクエストの例を追記しました。

Comment: 追記のご回答ありがとうございます。助かります。
また、postを送る時のデータの形式の指定で詰まっています。。
入力をtitleだけとした場合、データの送り方を教えていただきたいです。。

Comment: iOSクライアントからのデータの送信方法について、申し訳ありませんがiOSについては見識がないので回答できないです。しかし確認用に`curl`での実行例を追記したので参考になるかと思います。また、`protect_from_forgery` のオプションを変更する必要があったためそれも追記しました。